# How to get nodename of running celery worker?

Tags: celery, django-celery

I want to shut down celery workers specifically. I was using `app.control.broadcast('shutdown')`; however, this shutdown all the workers; therefore, I would like to pass the destination parameter.

When I run `ps -ef | grep celery`, I can see the `--hostname` on the process.

I know that the format is `{CELERYD_NODES}{NODENAME_SEP}{hostname}` from the utility function [`nodename`](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/_modules/celery/utils/nodenames.html#nodename)

```
destination =  ''.join(['celery', # CELERYD_NODES defined at /etc/default/newfies-celeryd
                        '@', # from celery.utils.__init__ import NODENAME_SEP
                         socket.gethostname()])
```

Is there a helper function which returns the nodename? I don't want to create it myself since I don't want to hardcode the value.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that's what you're looking for, but with [control.inspect](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/monitoring.html#management-command-line-utilities-inspect-control) you can get info about the workers, for example:

```
app = Celery('app_name', broker=...)
app.control.inspect().stats()  # statistics per worker
app.control.inspect().registered()  # registered tasks per each worker
app.control.inspect().active()  # active workers/tasks
```

so basically you can get the list of workers from each one of them:

```
app.control.inspect().stats().keys()
app.control.inspect().registered().keys()
app.control.inspect().active().keys()
```

for example:

```
>>> app.control.inspect().registered().keys()
dict_keys(['worker1@my-host-name', 'worker2@my-host-name', ..])
```

Comment: @AyodeleAshad is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @AyodeleAshad does it answer your question?

Comment: Apologies for the late reply, @ItayB; I wanted to invoke a lambda to gracefully shut down the terminating celery ec2 instance. I've used the approach which I've mentioned in the comment.